# Simple Injector usage for generic command handler

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, dependency-properties, simple-injector

The interfaces,commands and command handler set up as per instructions in Simpleinjector wiki.

```
public interface ICommand
{
    string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Command1 : ICommand
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Command2 : ICommand
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public interface ICommandHandler<TCommand>
{
    void Execute(TCommand Command);
}

public class Command1Handler : ICommandHandler<Command1>
{
    public void Execute(Command1 Command) {
        Console.WriteLine(Command.Name);
    }
}

public class Command2Handler : ICommandHandler<Command2>
{
    public void Execute(Command2 Command) {
        Console.WriteLine(Command.Name + "Hello");
    }
}
```

Decorator:

```
public class CommandDecorator<TCommand> : ICommandHandler<TCommand>
{
    private readonly ICommandHandler<TCommand> _handler;

    public CommandDecorator(ICommandHandler<TCommand> handler)
    {
        this._handler = handler;
    }

    public void Execute(TCommand command)
    {
        this._handler.Execute(command);
    }
}
```

Sample program

```
public class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Container container = new Container();

        //registering 
        container.RegisterAll<ICommand>(typeof(Command1), typeof(Command2));

        container.RegisterManyForOpenGeneric(
            typeof(ICommandHandler<>),
            typeof(ICommandHandler<>).Assembly);

        container.RegisterDecorator(typeof(ICommandHandler<>), 
            typeof(CommandDecorator<>));

        container.Verify();

        // sample test command 
        ICommand testcommand = new Command2();
        testcommand.Name = "command 1";

        var type = typeof(ICommandHandler<>).MakeGenericType(testcommand.GetType());

        dynamic instance = container.GetInstance(type);
        instance.Execute((dynamic)testcommand);
    }
}
```

Is this the right way to get the right handler for handling the command at runtime.
This is a sample and in the real app the commands are going to posted to a queue and a service is going to read the command and process it .
I guess the Decorator has to be used for that but am not able to get it working.
please suggest better options if any.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your commands (`Command1` and `Command2`) are not services: they should not be registered. They are runtime data (message) that you pass through your services (your command handlers).  So you should remove the `Collection.Register<ICommand>` (`RegisterAll` in v2) registration. It is of no use. You already see its of no use, since in your example you are newing the `Command2` up manually, which is the right thing to do.

What you are doing in the last three lines of code is dispatching a command of an unknown type to the right command handler registration. You always need some reflection to pull this of, since you need to build the closed `ICommandHandler<TCommand>` type based on the command type, which is something you don't know at compile time. Instead of using the C# `dynamic` keyword, you can also use the .NET reflection API, but in my experience using `dynamic` is better in this particular case. One important downside of the reflection API is that the API will always wrap any thrown exception (in case of a failure) with an `InvocationException` and that makes it harder to do certain exception handling up the call stack.

So long story short, this should be your registration:

```
Container container = new Container();

container.Register(
    typeof(ICommandHandler<>),
    typeof(ICommandHandler<>).Assembly);

container.RegisterDecorator(
    typeof(ICommandHandler<>), 
    typeof(CommandDecorator<>));
```

And this should be the dispatching logic:

```
var type = typeof(ICommandHandler<>).MakeGenericType(command.GetType());

dynamic handler = container.GetInstance(type);
handler.Execute((dynamic)command);
```