# Batch-registering open-generic implementations

Tags: c#, asp.net, dependency-injection, simple-injector

I'm trying to write my composition root in a future proof way so that when I add more commands that implement base entity with SimpleInjector 4 they automatically get picked up.

Domain classes look like this:

```
public interface ICommandHandler<TCommand> { . . . }

public class UpdateCommandHandler<T> : ICommandHandler<UpdateCommand<T>> 
    where T : EntityBase { . . . }

public class UpdateCommand<T> where T : EntityBase { . . . }

public abstract class EntityBase { . . . }
```

My API controllers then use command handlers as follows:

```
// With base entity
private ICommandHandler<UpdateCommand<BlogEntry>> updateBlogEntryCommandHandler;
// Without base entity
private ICommandHandler<AddBlogEntryCommentCommand> addBlogEntryCommentCommandHandler;
```

And my composition root looks like this:

```
// This works for all cases without as base entity e.g:
// private ICommandHandler<AddBlogEntryCommentCommand> addBlogEntryCommentCommandHandler;
container.Register(typeof(ICommandHandler<>), new[] { typeof(ICommandHandler<>).Assembly });


// And this works for when commands have a base entity but how do to I write it in a 
// generic, future-proof way like above?

container.Register<ICommandHandler<DeleteCommand<BlogEntryComment>>, DeleteCommandHandler<BlogEntryComment>>();
container.Register<ICommandHandler<UpdateCommand<BlogEntry>>, UpdateCommandHandler<BlogEntry>>();
container.Register<ICommandHandler<UpdateCommand<BlogEntryFile>>, UpdateCommandHandler<BlogEntryFile>>();
```

Note: this is a similar to [Simple Injector usage for generic command handler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23582234/simple-injector-usage-for-generic-command-handler) but it does not answer my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of making all registrations for the closed-generic versions of your open-generic implementations one by one, you can register them with their open-generic types instead:

```
container.Register(typeof(ICommandHandler<>), typeof(DeleteCommandHandler<>));
container.Register(typeof(ICommandHandler<>), typeof(UpdateCommandHandler<>));
```

Simple Injector will automatically close those types for you. Only when a new generic implementation is added, you will have to add it as registration to yuor Composition Root.

If you expect many generic types to be added, you can instead register all implementations at once using the following code:

```
var types = container.GetTypesToRegister(typeof(ICommandHandler<>),
    new[] { typeof(ICommandHandler<>).Assembly },
    new TypesToRegisterOptions { IncludeGenericTypeDefinitions = true });

container.Register(typeof(ICommandHandler<>),
    types.Where(t => !t.IsGenericTypeDefinition));

foreach (Type type in types.Where(t => t.IsGenericTypeDefinition))
{
    container.Register(typeof(ICommandHandler<>), type);
}
```

Due to a limitation `Register` in v4.0 (that is [planned to get fixed](https://github.com/simpleinjector/SimpleInjector/issues/420) in v4.1), `Register(Type, IEnumerable<Type>)` does not allow open-generic types to be passed in to the list of types. That's why you'll have to register the generic types separately (for now).

Comment: The first code snippet works fine but the second one doesn't. `GetTypesToRegister` expects an IEnumerable of assemblies for the second parameter. So I tried `var types = container.GetTypesToRegister(typeof(ICommandHandler<>), new[] { typeof(ICommandHandler<>).Assembly }, new TypesToRegisterOptions { IncludeGenericTypeDefinitions = true });` but that throws the following error: `The supplied list of types contains one or multiple open generic types, but this method is unable to handle open generic types because it can only map closed generic service types to a single implementation.`

Comment: @CatsPajamas: Appologies. Updated

Comment: Thanks a million that worked perfectly. I'm watching your open issue on the Github repo so I can update the code when you fix it. Cheers!